# Braintree client side with Java JSF?

Tags: jsf, braintree

[edited after comments by @Kukeltje]

I use JSF as a frontend framework. My goal is to set up the client side of braintree, as explained [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2).

In the tutorial by Braintree, this piece of code sends a client token with a post request:

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
var clientToken = "xxxxxx";

braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
</script>
```

I suspect that in the code above, the script generates parameters or a payload and attaches them to the post request, but I could be completely wrong. I have this code running and it works fine.

My question: how can I adapt the post request so that it would be replaced by the use of a bean, something like:

```
<h:form id="checkout">
    <h:CommandButton value="5€" actionListener="#{bean.submitToken()}"/>
</form>
```

The reason I would prefer JSF instead of pure html is that it makes easier the integration with the rest of my page, which already contains a `<h:form>`.

Note: thanks to the Braintree contributor for the answer. I actually solved the issue by using a Primefaces `<p:remoteCommand>`, see [this question and @BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255920/how-to-send-an-inputtext-to-a-bean-at-the-moment-a-post-request-is-made-in-jsf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Your question might be focused just on the JSF/Primefaces community, but I can answer the Braintree part. 
In many cases, including the `onPaymentMethodReceived` callback is a good way to handle any framework specific concerns. You can write a [custom javascript callback](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2#callbacks) to trigger whatever behavior you need while using the framework-specific code generation tools (like the action you specified). To do this, just specify it in your Braintree drop-in setup:

```
braintree.setup("CLIENT-TOKEN-FROM-SERVER", "dropin", {
  container: "dropin-container",
  onPaymentMethodReceived: function (obj) {
    // Do some logic in here.
    // When you're ready to submit the form:
    myForm.submit();
  }
});
```

Again, I'm not familiar with the specifics of JSF/Primefaces, but the Drop-in is really flexible when you start using callbacks.

Comment: If you replace the `p:commandButton` with an `h:commandButton` with a nested `f:ajax` it becomes a generic jsf question, not PrimeFaces specific. Can you enhance your question then so it becomes a more logical combination with the question?

Comment: just did that. Would appreciate if you could remove the down vote (if that's yours, that is) :-)

Comment: Should have stated 'answer'. And I do have a downvote, since I totally fail to see the relation with jsf, even after your edit. And the answer makes it even more blurry. Regardless of what is used (braintree in this case). And looking at the answer, the braintree people don't have a real clue either. And looking at the 3 downvotes, I'm not the only one…  so I'm not saying there is **no** relation with jsf, but I totally fail to see what it is

Comment: But it might be that the answer is valid an you only want the callback to your bean, but then the question is still unclear.

Comment: I edited the question to make my need absolutely clear.