# How to send an inputText to a bean at the moment a post request is made in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The constraint I have is that my JSF + Primefaces page must include a post request in straight html:

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
</form>
```

And I can't touch that.

On the same page, I have an inputText where the user will put their email address:
`<p:inputText value="#{bean.emailAddress}"/>`

When the button in the `<form>` is clicked for the post request, I'd like to have the inputText submitted as well and sent to a bean on my server. How could I achieve that? Just including `<p:inputText value="#{bean.emailAddress}"/>` inside the `<form></form>` tag seems not to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook a JavaScript event listener to that form which triggers a `<p:remoteCommand>` processing at least the `<p:inputText>` of interest.

As you're using PrimeFaces, you'll have jQuery at hands. So, this should do:

```
<form id="checkout" ...>
    ...
</form>

<h:form>
    <p:inputText ... />
    <p:remoteCommand name="checkout" process="@form" action="#{bean.checkout}" />
</h:form>
```

```
$(document).on("submit", "#checkout", function() {
    checkout();
});
```